# Django RadioSelect field not rendering correctly

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-filter

I'm using Django FilterSet to enable the user to filter a list of products on my website. Everything is working perfectly, I'm using standard html code to display a form. However there is a RadioSelect field that is not rendering correclty and I don't understand why. I provide you below the relevant parts of my code as well as a screenshot of the rendering problem. Does anyone know how I can solve that ?

filters.py

```
class PlatFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    titre = django_filters.CharFilter(
        field_name='titre', label='Mot clé :', lookup_expr='icontains',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    )
    prix_min = django_filters.NumberFilter(
        field_name='prix', label='Prix minimum :', lookup_expr='gte',
        widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    )
    prix_max = django_filters.NumberFilter(
        field_name='prix', label='Prix maximum :', lookup_expr='lte',
        widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    )
    nb_portions = django_filters.NumberFilter(
        field_name='nb_portions', label='Nombre de portions minimum :', lookup_expr='gte',
        widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    )
    date_prep = django_filters.DateFilter(
        field_name='date_prep__date', label='Date de préparation (format JJ/MM/AAAA)', lookup_expr='exact',
        widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    )

    CHOICES = ((True, 'Oui'), (False, 'Non'))

    is_delivering = django_filters.BooleanFilter(
        field_name='chef__is_delivering', label='Livraison comprise',
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}, choices=CHOICES),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Plat
        fields = ['titre', 'nb_portions', 'date_prep']
```

html file (using Bootstrap)

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="filters shadow-sm rounded bg-white mb-4">
    <div class="filters-header border-bottom pl-4 pr-4 pt-3 pb-3">
      <h5 class="m-0" style="font-size: 200%">Filtrer par</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="filters-body">
      <form method="get">
         <div class="well">
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 pl-5 pb-4 pt-4 pr-5">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for field in filter.form %}
                <div class="fieldWrapper form-group" style="font-size: 150%">
                   {{ field.label_tag }}
                   {{ field }}
                </div>
                {% endfor %}

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Rechercher
                </button>
            </div>
           </div>
         </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot of the problem :
[image: rendering problem]

Comment: Please show the HTML source for the specific field (what your browser source shows). And the corresponding css for the classes of this field. That's how you actually debug this, in your browser developer tools.

Comment: The problem is you're using the class `form-control` instead of `form-check` and `form-check-input` (see [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios))

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've changed ```form-control``` to ```form-check``` in the filters.py file, it looks better but it's still not very good. How am I supposed to specifiy in html that I want a ```form-check-input``` since I'm using a for loop to display all the fields of my form ?

Comment: You need to use a custom widget, there's one [here](https://github.com/zostera/django-bootstrap4/blob/master/src/bootstrap4/templates/bootstrap4/widgets/radio_select_button_group.html) with an example of how to use [here](https://django-bootstrap4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/widgets.html#radioselectbuttongroup). But it's based on a button group so i'm not sure if it renders the exact same way as a `form-check` + `form-check-input` would work. But you can change the code yourself to make it the correct inputs or search more on the internet if someone already made a widget.